# How to vectorize a function over a list of unequal length arrays in JAX

Tags: python, vectorization, jax

This is a minimal example of the real larger problem I am facing. Consider the function below:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
def test(x):
    return jnp.sum(x)
```

I tried to vectorize it by:

```
v_test = jax.vmap(test)
```

My inputs to `test` look like:

```
x1 = jnp.array([1,2,3])
x2 = jnp.array([4,5,6,7])
x3 = jnp.array([8,9])
x4 = jnp.array([10])
```

and my input to `v_test` is:

```
x = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

If I try:

```
v_test(x)
```

I get the error below:

```
ValueError: vmap got inconsistent sizes for array axes to be mapped:
the tree of axis sizes is:
([3, 4, 2, 1],)
```

Is there a way to vectorize `test` over a list of unequal length arrays?
I could avoid this by padding so the arrays have the same length, however, padding is not desired.

Answer (score 2):

JAX does not support ragged arrays, (i.e. arrays in which each row has a different number of elements) so there is currently no way to use `vmap` for this kind of data. Your best bet is probably to use a Python `for` loop:

```py
y = [test(xi) for xi in x]
```

Alternatively, you might be able to express the operation you have in mind in terms of [`segment_sum`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.ops.segment_sum.html) or similar operations. For example:

```py
segments = jnp.concatenate([i * jnp.ones_like(xi) for i, xi in enumerate(x)])
result = jax.ops.segment_sum(jnp.concatenate(x), segments)
print(result)
# [ 6 22 17 10]
```

Another possibility is to pad the input arrays so that they can fit into a standard, non-ragged 2D array.

Comment: Does the HLO representation of comprehension have the same limitations as a native `for` loop (with back-prop in mind)?

Also, mapping the second index is not required in the straight reduction example above, but if it was one could use `map_j = jnp.concatenate([jnp.arange(xi.size) for xi in x])`

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps create a new post with more details? Comment threads aren't a great medium for asking additional questions.